# Plotting data points on a map in R with unknown latitude and longitude format

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, latitude-longitude, ggmap

I have no experience working with maps, but I tried to plot my sampling plots using the included latitude and longitude columns of my dataset.

I have followed a post and tried this so far, with no success.

```
> head(test,15)
       Country LATITUDE LONGITUDE
3      Austria   474600    161900
4      Finland   693400    285300
5        Italy   415000    133500
6  Switzerland   470300     84200
9      Estonia   593300    260200
10    Slovenia   462200    135600
11    Bulgaria   424600    234500
13     Austria   480600    125200
14     Finland   615200    241200
27     Finland   615100    241800
28     Belgium   510400     30200
29 Switzerland   474100     83200
32    Slovenia   462900    163100
35      Poland   543300    181600
38     Austria   472900    132500

library(rworldmap)
newmap <- getMap(resolution = "low")
plot(newmap, xlim = c(-20, 59), ylim = c(35, 71), asp = 1)
points(test$LONGITUDE, test$LATITUDE, col = "red", cex = .6)
```

I think probably R does not recognise these latitude and longitude formats?
Thanks

Comment: Correct. Those are integers with 6 digits.  Do you have any information about them? It is possible to guess, but usually it's best to have some idea.

Comment: No idea at all. I included the name of the country were these points are located so that someone can figure out what these coordinates may represent, but other than that this is all I have. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you look up latitude and longitude for the a few of the countries (probably some centroid location), or check the capital's coordinates. Perhaps if your figures are close you can convert these numbers then by inserting a period (dot) after the first two digits (at least for the latitudes).  For longitudes, you might need to insert a trailing zero in five-digit ones, and then insert the period after the second digit from the left.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to reprojecting coordinates into lat/lon degrees (which might prove troublesome if you are unaware of what coordinate system your datapoints are currently in) is to use package ggmap:

```
library(ggmap)

#get coordinates from google maps
coords = geocode(as.character(test$Country))

#add points to map
points(coords$lon,coords$lat,col="red")
```

Of course since the package uses google maps for finding the coordinates it will only work for simpler tasks (such as finding coordinates of countries), and you are limitid by the api to a maximum of 2500 queries a day.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, within each country sometimes there are several points. Besides, the final aim is publication, so accuracy of exact location of each plot is important. Thanks again

Comment: 1 -Take a small smaple of your table, for example Finland.
2- Make guesses on what projection the  could be.                                               3- Try these different projects until your points are mapped in Finland. Maybe this could help a little. But it seems you have uncommon projection system. https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf